# Cómo puedo obtener el valor en tipo String de esta variable

Tags: java, string

Tengo esta variable "id" la cual la obtengo con el get de la clase Detallepedido, donde pedidoId es de tipo Pedido. Quisiera convertir el valor de la variable id a String ya que quiero enviarle este valor a un método String que tiene una consulta Query.

```
Pedido id=detallePedido.getPedidoId();
```

Es decir quiero obtener el valor de Pedido id y luego asignarselo a una variable String "valorFinal" y enviarselo a mi método String;

```
String valorFinal=....          
lista=ejbFacade.listaFiltradaDetallePedido(valorFinal);
```

Mi clase Detallepedido:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DETALLEPEDIDO")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Detallepedido.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Detallepedido d")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Detallepedido.findById", query = "SELECT d FROM Detallepedido d WHERE d.id = :id")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Detallepedido.findByCantidad", query = "SELECT d FROM Detallepedido d WHERE d.cantidad = :cantidad")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Detallepedido.findByPrecio", query = "SELECT d FROM Detallepedido d WHERE d.precio = :precio")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Detallepedido.findByTotal", query = "SELECT d FROM Detallepedido d WHERE d.total = :total")})
public class Detallepedido implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
private BigDecimal id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "CANTIDAD")
private BigInteger cantidad;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "PRECIO")
private BigDecimal precio;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "TOTAL")
private BigDecimal total;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "detallepedidoId")
private Collection<Despacho> despachoCollection;
@JoinColumn(name = "PEDIDO_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Pedido pedidoId;
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCTO_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Producto productoId;

public Detallepedido() {
}

public Detallepedido(BigDecimal id) {
    this.id = id;
}
 public Detallepedido(BigInteger cantidad, BigDecimal precio, BigDecimal total) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.total = total;
}
public Detallepedido(BigDecimal id, BigInteger cantidad, BigDecimal precio, BigDecimal total) {
    this.id = id;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.total = total;
}

public BigDecimal getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public BigInteger getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}

public void setCantidad(BigInteger cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}

public BigDecimal getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(BigDecimal precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public BigDecimal getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(BigDecimal total) {
    this.total = total;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<Despacho> getDespachoCollection() {
    return despachoCollection;
}

public void setDespachoCollection(Collection<Despacho> despachoCollection) {
    this.despachoCollection = despachoCollection;
}

public Pedido getPedidoId() {
    return pedidoId;
}

public void setPedidoId(Pedido pedidoId) {
    this.pedidoId = pedidoId;
}

public Producto getProductoId() {
    return productoId;
}

public void setProductoId(Producto productoId) {
    this.productoId = productoId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Detallepedido)) {
        return false;
    }
    Detallepedido other = (Detallepedido) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Detallepedido[ id=" + id + " ]";
}

}
```

Mi clase Pedido:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PEDIDO")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Pedido.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Pedido p")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Pedido.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Pedido p WHERE p.id = :id")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Pedido.findByFecha", query = "SELECT p FROM Pedido p WHERE p.fecha = :fecha")})
public class Pedido implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
private BigDecimal id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "FECHA")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date fecha;
@JoinColumn(name = "CLIENTE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Cliente clienteId;
@JoinColumn(name = "ESTADOPEDIDO_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Estadopedido estadopedidoId;
@JoinColumn(name = "USUARIO_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Usuario usuarioId;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pedidoId")
private Collection<Detallepedido> detallepedidoCollection;

public Pedido() {
}

public Pedido(BigDecimal id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Pedido(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}
public Pedido(BigDecimal id, Date fecha) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public BigDecimal getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public Cliente getClienteId() {
    return clienteId;
}

public void setClienteId(Cliente clienteId) {
    this.clienteId = clienteId;
}

public Estadopedido getEstadopedidoId() {
    return estadopedidoId;
}

public void setEstadopedidoId(Estadopedido estadopedidoId) {
    this.estadopedidoId = estadopedidoId;
}

public Usuario getUsuarioId() {
    return usuarioId;
}

public void setUsuarioId(Usuario usuarioId) {
    this.usuarioId = usuarioId;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<Detallepedido> getDetallepedidoCollection() {
    return detallepedidoCollection;
}

public void setDetallepedidoCollection(Collection<Detallepedido> detallepedidoCollection) {
    this.detallepedidoCollection = detallepedidoCollection;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Pedido)) {
        return false;
    }
    Pedido other = (Pedido) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Cliente: "+clienteId+".  Fecha de pedido: "+ fecha+" id: "+id+"" ;
}

}
```

Ahora mi Facade:

```
@Stateless
public class DetallepedidoFacade extends AbstractFacade<Detallepedido> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.mycompany_proyectoProgra3_1_war_1.0- 
SNAPSHOTPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public DetallepedidoFacade() {
    super(Detallepedido.class);
}

public List<Detallepedido> listaFiltradaDetallePedido(String id ){
    Query consulta=em.createNativeQuery("SELECT PRODUCTO_ID, CANTIDAD, PRECIO, TOTAL FROM DETALLEPEDIDO WHERE PEDIDO_ID LIKE ('"+id+"')", Detallepedido.class);
    List<Detallepedido> lista=consulta.getResultList();
    return lista;
}

}
```

Mi clase Controller:

```
 @Named("detallepedidoController")
 @SessionScoped
 public class DetallepedidoController implements Serializable {

@EJB
private com.mycompany.proyectoprogra3_1.DetallepedidoFacade ejbFacade;
private List<Detallepedido> items = null;
private List<Detallepedido> detallePedidos;
private List<Detallepedido> lista;
private Detallepedido selected;
private Detallepedido detallePedido;
private Pedido pedido;
 Detallepedido detalle;
 double gasto;

public double getGasto() {
    return gasto;
}

public void setGasto(double gasto) {
    this.gasto = gasto;
}
 public DetallepedidoController(double gasto){
     this.gasto=gasto;
 }
public DetallepedidoController() {
}

public Detallepedido getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Detallepedido selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

protected void setEmbeddableKeys() {
}

protected void initializeEmbeddableKey() {
}

  private DetallepedidoFacade getFacade() {
    return ejbFacade;
  }

  public Detallepedido prepareCreate() {
     selected = new Detallepedido();
    initializeEmbeddableKey();
    return selected;
}

   public void create() {
    persist(PersistAction.CREATE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("DetallepedidoCreated"));
    if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
        items = null;    // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
    }
}

public void update() {
    persist(PersistAction.UPDATE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("DetallepedidoUpdated"));
}

public void destroy() {
    persist(PersistAction.DELETE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("DetallepedidoDeleted"));
    if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
        selected = null; // Remove selection
        items = null;    // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
    }
}

public List<Detallepedido> getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getFacade().findAll();
    }
    return items;
}

private void persist(PersistAction persistAction, String successMessage) {
    if (selected != null) {
        setEmbeddableKeys();
        try {
            if (persistAction != PersistAction.DELETE) {
                getFacade().edit(selected);
            } else {
                getFacade().remove(selected);
            }
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(successMessage);
        } catch (EJBException ex) {
            String msg = "";
            Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
            if (cause != null) {
                msg = cause.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
            if (msg.length() > 0) {
                JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(msg);
            } else {
                JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }
}

public Detallepedido getDetallepedido(java.math.BigDecimal id) {
    return getFacade().find(id);
}

public List<Detallepedido> getItemsAvailableSelectMany() {
    return getFacade().findAll();
}

public List<Detallepedido> getItemsAvailableSelectOne() {
    return getFacade().findAll();
}

@FacesConverter(forClass = Detallepedido.class)
public static class DetallepedidoControllerConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        DetallepedidoController controller = (DetallepedidoController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "detallepedidoController");
        return controller.getDetallepedido(getKey(value));
    }

    java.math.BigDecimal getKey(String value) {
        java.math.BigDecimal key;
        key = new java.math.BigDecimal(value);
        return key;
    }

    String getStringKey(java.math.BigDecimal value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(value);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (object instanceof Detallepedido) {
            Detallepedido o = (Detallepedido) object;
            return getStringKey(o.getId());
        } else {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "object {0} is of type {1}; expected type: {2}", new Object[]{object, object.getClass().getName(), Detallepedido.class.getName()});
            return null;
        }
    }

}

public List<Detallepedido> getDetallePedidos() {
    return detallePedidos;
}

public void setDetallePedidos(List<Detallepedido> detallePedidos) {
    this.detallePedidos = detallePedidos;
}

public List<Detallepedido> getLista() {
    return lista;
}

public void setLista(List<Detallepedido> lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
detallePedido=new Detallepedido();
detallePedidos=ejbFacade.findAll();
pedido=new Pedido();
lista= new ArrayList();
detalle=new Detallepedido();
}

public Detallepedido getDetalle() {
    return detalle;
}

public void setDetalle(Detallepedido detalle) {
    this.detalle = detalle;
}

public Detallepedido getDetallePedido() {
    return detallePedido;
}

public void setDetallePedido(Detallepedido detallePedido) {
    this.detallePedido = detallePedido;
}

public void registrarDetalle(){
    try{

        BigDecimal a=detallePedido.getPrecio();
        BigInteger b=detallePedido.getCantidad();
        double precio=a.doubleValue();
        int cantidad=b.intValue();
        double total=precio * cantidad ;
        gasto=gasto+total;
        BigDecimal totalFinal=BigDecimal.valueOf(total); 
        detallePedido.setTotal(totalFinal);
        ejbFacade.create(detallePedido);
        Pedido id=detallePedido.getPedidoId();   
        String valorId=String.valueOf(id);
        lista=ejbFacade.listaFiltradaDetallePedido(valorId); //AQUI QUIERO MANDAR MI STRING
    }catch(Exception ex){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new 
 FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "AVISO", "ERROR AL REGISTRAR 
DETALLE DE PEDIDO"));
    }
}

public Pedido getPedido() {
    return pedido;
}

public void setPedido(Pedido pedido) {
    this.pedido = pedido;
}


}

}
```

.xhtml:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="pruebas2.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="titulo">Pedidos</ui:define>
            <ui:define name="menu">
                 <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-black" href="#">Pedidos</a>
                  <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-black" href="index.xhtml">Cerrar Sesión</a>
           </ui:define>           
            <ui:define name="contenido">              
                    <h:form> 
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                       <p:outputLabel value="Fecha" for="fecha" />
                       <p:calendar id="fecha" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="#{pedidoController.pedido.fecha}" title="#{bundle.EditPedidoTitle_fecha}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditPedidoRequiredMessage_fecha}" showOn="button"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Cliente" for="clienteId" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="clienteId" value="#{pedidoController.pedido.clienteId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditPedidoRequiredMessage_clienteId}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{clienteController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                                           var="clienteIdItem"
                                           itemValue="#{clienteIdItem}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Estado" for="estadopedidoId" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="estadopedidoId" value="#{pedidoController.pedido.estadopedidoId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditPedidoRequiredMessage_estadopedidoId}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{estadopedidoController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                                           var="estadopedidoIdItem"
                                           itemValue="#{estadopedidoIdItem}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu> 
                    </h:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton id="agregar_pedido" actionListener="#{pedidoController.registrarPedido()}" value="Aceptar"/><br/><br/>                 
                    </h:form>
                <h:form>
                    <p:commandButton id="agregar_detalle" value="Agregar" onclick="PF('w_dialogo_detalle').show();" />
                 <p:commandButton id="finalizar"  value="Finalizar" actionListener="#{plantillaController.finalizar()}" />
                </h:form>                
                <h:form id="form_tablaDetalle" >
                    <p:dataTable id="datalist" emptyMessage="Ningún producto agregado" value="#{detallepedidoController.lista}" var="item"
                                 selectionMode="single" selection="#{detallepedidoController.selected}"
                                 paginator="true"
                                 rowKey="#{item.id}"
                                 rows="10"
                                 rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"
                                 >  
                 
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Producto"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.productoId.nombre}"/>
                        </p:column>                       
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Cantidad"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.cantidad}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Precio"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.precio}"/>
                        </p:column>     
                         <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Gasto"/>
                            </f:facet>
                             <h:outputText value="#{item.total}"/>
                        </p:column>   
                    </p:dataTable> 
                    <b><p:outputLabel value="Total:  " for="total"></p:outputLabel></b>
                    <p:commandButton id="total" value="#{detallepedidoController.gasto}" />
                </h:form>
                    <p:dialog id="dialogo_agregar_detalle" widgetVar="w_dialogo_detalle" resizable="false" closeOnEscape="true" header="Agregar Detalle" modal="true">
                       
                     <h:form id="form_agregar_detalle">
                     <p:growl id="growl_DetallePedido" autoUpdate="true" /> 
                         <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Pedido " for="pedidoId" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="pedidoId" value="#{detallepedidoController.detallePedido.pedidoId}" required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Pedido es obligatorio" 
                                 validatorMessage="Ingrese Pedido">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{pedidoController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                                           var="pedidoIdItem"
                                           itemValue="#{pedidoIdItem}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Cantidad" for="cantidad" />
                        <p:inputText id="cantidad" value="#{detallepedidoController.detallePedido.cantidad}" title="#{bundle.CreateDetallepedidoTitle_cantidad}" required="true"
                                     requiredMessage="Campo cantidad es obligatorio"  validatorMessage="Ingrese cantidad"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Precio" for="precio" />
                        <p:inputText id="precio" value="#{detallepedidoController.detallePedido.precio}" title="#{bundle.CreateDetallepedidoTitle_precio}" required="true" 
                                     requiredMessage="Campo precio es obligatorio" validatorMessage="Ingrese precio"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Producto" for="productoId" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="productoId" value="#{detallepedidoController.detallePedido.productoId}" required="true"
                                         requiredMessage="Campo producto es obligatorio" validatorMessage="Ingrese producto">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{productoController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                                           var="productoIdItem"
                                           itemValue="#{productoIdItem}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                            <p:commandButton update="growl_DetallePedido,:form_tablaDetalle:datalist" actionListener="#{detallepedidoController.registrarDetalle()}" value="Agregar"  oncomplete="PF('w_dialogo_detalle').hide();" />    
                            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" icon="ui-icon-close" immediate="true" onclick="PF('w_dialogo_detalle').hide();" />                    
                        </h:form>
                    </p:dialog>   
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
     
</html>
```

Acá está mi xhtml donde yo creo el pedido, luego le doy al botón agregar y me muestra un dialogo con los campos de la tabla Detallepedido, al darle click ejecuto mi método detallepedidoController.registrarDetalle(); dentro del mismo metodo ejecuto el método (que se encuentra en el facade) que espera la string y luego mostrarlo en una tabla abajo, en mi BD se crea el pedido en la tabla Pedido, tambien al agregar datos se crean en mi tabla Detallepedido, pero en mi tabla de abajo no muestra los datos segun el Id que envío. ya probé mi query en mi sql developer y si me arroja datos. Entonces creo que mi problema esta al mandarle el dato en lista=ejbFacade.listaFiltradaDetallePedido(valorId); tal vez no encuentre el valor de valorId (eso creo).
NOTA: se que los tipos que definí en mi columnas son demasiadas grandes.

Comment: Sobreescribe **toString** en la clase Pedido

Comment: Mira si el objeto `Pedido` tiene algún método que devuelva la id en formato String

Answer (score 1):

Puedes convertirlo de dos formas:

Utilizando `String.valueOf()` que convierte en `String` un `objeto` o `valor` y en tu caso quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```
   String idPedigo =String.valueOf(detallePedido.getPedidoId());
```

O puedes utilizar `toString()`que convierte un valor a `String`

Y te quedaría así:

```
String idPedido =detallePedido.getPedidoId().toString();
```

Para asignar el valor debes hacer lo siguiente

```
String valorFinal=idPedido
```

Entiendo que tienes un objeto `Pedido`
Y lo inicializas así:

```
Pedido detallePedido = new Pedido();
```

Y dentro de `detallePedido`  accedes al `id` . Para convertirlo a string debes declarar la variable `id` como `String` no como `objeto`

Comment: Angabo edite mi pregunta

Comment: Probe con esto pero no me funciona: 
            Pedidoid=detallePedido.getPedidoId();   
            String valorId=id.toString();
            lista=ejbFacade.listaFiltradaDetallePedido(valorId);

Comment: No puedo hacerla String ya que en mi BD  Pedido id es Number, y en mi clase  Detallepedido pedidoId es de tipo Pedido para el Join

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon todo el código necesario para que te podamos ayudar mejor

Comment: Ya la he editado

Comment: La conversión la veo bien, depura a ver si te tiene valor el id

Answer (score -1):

```
valorFinal=idPedido.toString()// (aunque no sé muy bien para que quieres este string)
lista=ejbFacade.listaFiltradaDetallePedido(Integer.parseInt(valorFinal)); //(Me imagino que del id no te interesará tu String, por eso te lo vuelvo a pasar a entero)
```

Quizá la respuesta no sea lo que buscas. No acabo de entender tu pregunta.

Comment: Esta buscando convertir un `objeto` a `String`, no un `String` a `int`

Comment: Pues le quitas el parseInt y listo... No creo que fuese tan descabellado pensar que se filtraba un pedido con el id como int, lo raro es filtrarlo con un id siendo un string

Comment: Si leemos su pregunta si es descabellado. Aparte un id puede ser alfanumerico perfectamente.

Comment: Qué es descabellado, buscar un Id como un entero? Tienes razón en que puede ser alfanumérico, pero bueno, que no pasa nada que le quitamos el parseInt y tenemos la solución compañero. Por cierto, lee lo que dice el amigo arriba de que su Id es un numero :)

Comment: Es descabellado hacer un parseInt cuando su metodo espera un String. Por que el dice que su campo es Number pero el método de la query espera un String.

Comment: Pues entonces una de dos, o tienes el método mal o la base de datos. Tú cómo sabes que su método espera un String? O la única solución válida es cambiar el tipo de la BD y no vale hacerlo del método de la clase Pedido? Que la explicación sea vaga, no implica que mis ideas sean descabelladas

Comment: El método espera un String porque lo dice el propio usuario "enviarle este valor a un método String". La explicación no es perfecta pero es simple, mas bien la comprensión ha sido vaga.

Comment: Insisto en que es mucho más sencillo cambiar el parámetro de un método, o el atributo de una clase, que cambiar el atributo de una base de datos. Para mi la explicación no es clara, ya que no tenemos ni la clase pedido, ni ningún método que pueda ayudarnos a parte del toString() o del charAt() si te apetece complicarte aun mas. En vez de quedarte con mi vaguedad, podrías no aconsejar cambiar bases de datos en vez de atributos de una clase.

Comment: Nadie ha hablado de cambiar base de datos ni nada. Si la explicación no es clara tienes la seccion de comentarios para aclarar cosas. La sección de respuestas es para respuestas a la pregunta no para cosas del tipo "a ver si es algo como lo que me invento". Y te repito nadie ha hablado de cambiar la bbdd, simplemente se te ha dicho que el método espera un String y eso es a lo que hay que atenerse, lo que haga despues con el String hasta la bbdd no esta dentro de la pregunta, porque ni siquiera sabemos si puede modificar ese metodo.

Comment: Bueno, pero te pongas como te pongas la solución que yo dí, si concuerda con su base de datos, y eso que era vaga e inventada a ver si colaba. Aun así, con mi respuesta dije que a lo mejor no era lo que buscaba que quería más información, porque era (y es) muy poca por muy claro que lo tengas tú todo.

Comment: Tu solucion no sirve porque va a dar una excepcion al compilar ya que espera un String y recibe un Int.

Comment: Bueno, pues volvemos al principio, habrá que cambiar el parámetro del método y el atributo de la clase. No sé si se podrá o no como tú dices, pero desde luego que más restrictivo es un cambio en una base de datos. Que sí compañero que sí, que a lo mejor interpreté mal la primera vez, pero que no estamos aquí para eso. Yo lo interpreté mal y di la solución mal, tu lo has interpretado y tampoco has dado una solución buena. Yo al menos desde mi locura y mis invenciones propongo una solución válida después de la primera  que fue mala por leer mal o por vaguedad o por lo que te de a ti la gana

Comment: Ya la he editado

Comment: Para que funcione deberías cambiar o bien el campo de tu base de datos, o bien tu clase para que los datos concuerden. O números o Strings. Yo, personalmente te aconsejo no tocar la BD si funciona, y cambiar el código a no ser que no te quede otra